# Run SSH commands on Azure Linux VM via Azure Automation

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, azure-automation

I'm trying to use azure automation to run SSH commands on a Linux VM on Azure but failing to establish a connection. I've tried a couple of SSH modules. Error is:

```
GraphTrace:{ Activity:"New-SshSession",
Event:"ActivityOutput",          Time:"2017-10-12T11:10:10.6189570Z",
Values:{ Status:"OK", Data:["Unable to connect to 52.xxx.xxx.xxx: Exception calling \"Connect\" with \"0\" argument(s): 
\"Session operation has timed out\""] }

52.xxx.xxx.xxx is the pip

Module is: SSHSessions (v1.8)
```

To test I've not used parameters and used the username, password and IP (+port) that I can connect in directly from a BASH shell. NSG has 22 open to all

(The script is just to backup a database (Neo4j). I'm opting to use automation as opposed to DSC so I can avoid running more modules on the VM, but open to other ideas of a way to do this, I'm a bit of a linux noob, so just hacking my way through!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, `New-SshSession` command will not work for Azure automation runbook, because Azure automation run script with SYSTEM account.

As a workaround, we can use `Azure custom script extension` with Linux VM, write a script and upload it to Azure, then use that extension to run it.
[image]
[image]
More information about Azure custom extension, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/extensions-customscript).

By the way, `New-SshSession` works for Azure HybridWorker, maybe we can try to use it.

Here the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-azure-automation/suggestions/9776280-make-ssh-calls-from-runbooks) about Automation runbooks SSH to Linux VM, I have upvote it, that feedback will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.